# How to use Universal Connection Pool (UCP) with Sybase?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection-pooling, sap-iq

Trying to configure connection pooling in standalone Java application.
Using UCP and Sybase DB. I am stuck at Connection Factory ClassName to use for Sybase.

Tried using com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnectionPoolDataSource but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like using a Connection from some props file, except you create a DataSource Object first, then retrieve your connection from the DataSource.  I can't give you a better example than is in the Sybase documentation here...

[Jconnect 7 (Jconn4) docs...Scroll to page 9](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/pdf/prjdbc0700.pdf)

Comment: As I already said... I followed exactly same example with SybConnectionPoolDataSource. It doesn't give me db connection pooling by itself. I will need to use it with some connection pooling implementation like UCP. I didn't find any way to do so until now.